# Cannot align form-group line inside form-inline inside a panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

The following code describes a panel in one of my webpages:

```
  <div class="row" id="tool_row">
<div class="panel panel-info" id="edit_toolbar" style="width:66%">

  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1 class="panel-title"><b>Herramientas</b></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body">      
    <div class="form-inline" style="width:100%">          
      <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="loadActForEdition(-1)">Nueva actividad</button>  

      <p style="margin-top:10px"><label class="control-label"> Opciones de Filtrado </label></p>

      <label class="control-label"> Últimos </label> <input class="form-control" id="ndays" style="width:5%" onkeypress='getEnter(event,"fillTaskTable")'> <label class="control-label" style="margin-right:10px"> días </label>

      <select data-placeholder="Filtrar por proyecto" class="chosen" id="proyect_box" onchange=fillTaskTable()></select>
      <select data-placeholder="Filtrar por estado" class="chosen" id="status_box" onchange=fillTaskTable()> </select>                

      <div class="form-group pull-right">
    <label class="control-label"> Número de resultados </label> <input class="form-control" id="nrows" style="width:15%" value=30 onkeypress='getEnter(event,"fillTaskTable")'>
      </div>

    </div> <!--form_inline-->               
  </div> <!--Panel body-->

</div>  <!--del panel-->
```

However it is not working as expected, since there is an annoying space between that form group and the right side of the panel, that I've been trying to eliminate and I have not been able to do it.

[image: White space beside the box that contains the 30]

What I want to do is simply to eliminate that whitespace. I want the label and the textbox, as a group, to be right aligned in the panel.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please Provide proper code! Place demo text in php script

Comment: The php code only adds a select box and button in certain cases. It should not have anything to do with the problem, as that white space is there wheater the button and the select box are present or not. I have eliminated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `form-group` is on the right but with larger width hence you can't make out if it has gone to the right. Align the contents inside to the right or make the width of `form-group` smaller.

HTML

```
 <div class="form-group pull-right newclass">
  <label class="control-label"> Número de resultados </label> <input class="form-control" id="nrows" style="width:15%" value=30 onkeypress='getEnter(event,"fillTaskTable")'>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .newclass { text-align: right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant see the width provided for the form-group/pull-right div. Probably it is larger than its content. Setting the text align of the div to right should do the trick.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

make two container divs an make them pull left and right and giv **text-right** to pull-right class

```
<div class="form-group pull-right text-right" style="padding:0;margin:0;">
</div>

<div class="form-group pull-right text-right" style="padding:0;margin:0;">
</div>
```

### Here is the snippet

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<<div class="row" id="tool_row">
    <div class="panel panel-info" id="edit_toolbar" style="width:66%">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h1 class="panel-title"><b>Herramientas</b></h1>

        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="loadTaskForEdition(-1)">Nueva Tarea</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="loadActForEdition(-1)">Nueva actividad</button>
                <p style="margin-top:10px">
                    <label class="control-label">Opciones de Filtrado</label>
                </p>
                <div class="pull-left" style="" apdding:0;margin:0; ">
      <label class="control-label "> Últimos </label> <input class="form-control " id="ndays " style="width:5% " onkeypress='getEnter(event,"fillTaskTable ")'> <label class="control-label " style="margin-right:10px "> días </label>       

     <select data-placeholder="Filtrar por usuario " class="chosen " id="username_box " onchange=fillTaskTable()> </select>
</div>
      <div class="form-group pull-right text-right" style="padding:0;margin:0;">
    <label class="control-label "> Número de resultados </label> <input class="form-control " id="nrows " style="width:15% " value=30 onkeypress='getEnter(event,"fillTaskTable ")'>
      </div>

    </div> <!--form_inline-->               
  </div> <!--Panel body-->

</div>  <!--del panel-->
```